# Image does not stay in JTextPane in Java

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, jtextpane, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to transfer images (drawings) from the clipboard to JTextPane or JTextArea.
The attached code correctly displays the images in these windows but the images disappear as soon as I take the cursor off the windows. How can I fix the images in the JText...? Something is clearly missing in my code. My internet search did not produce anything useful. I did not have this problem with C#. I would highly appreciate your help.

```
    private void jTextPaneStructuresMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)     {                                                 

    TransferImage.TransferableImage newImage = new TransferImage.TransferableImage(image);

        transferable = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents( null );

        if ( transferable != null && transferable.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) ) {
            try {
                image = (Image)transferable.getTransferData( DataFlavor.imageFlavor );
                Image cpImage = newImage.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
                jTextPaneStructures.getGraphics().drawImage(cpImage, 0, 0, rootPane);
            } catch (    UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WeeklyData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }     



    /* This is what TransferImage.TransferableImage refers to */

    public class TransferImage 
{ 
  static class TransferableImage implements Transferable
  {
      /* -- image for transfer */
        private final Image image;

      /* -- constructor */

      public TransferableImage(Image image)
      {
      this.image = image;
      {
   }
      }
    @Override
   public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors()
         {
            return new DataFlavor[]
            { 
                DataFlavor.imageFlavor
            };
         }

    @Override
   public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor )
        {
            return flavor == DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
        }

    @Override
   public Image getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor ) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
        if ( isDataFlavorSupported( flavor ) )
        {
             return image;
        } 
        else
        {
             throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Clarification of my earlier post: the images disappear as soon as I take the cursor off the windows AND click somewhere else. They appear again when I click in JTextPane or JTextArea again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute getGraphics().drawImage in your listener you do draw the image on the JTextArea, but as soon as the systems repaints the JTextArea your image disappears because it's not stored in the JTextArea.

I think you should follow a different approach:

- Write a new class that extends JTextArea (MyTextArea)
- include a private property to store the image (myImage)
- provide a set method to set the image (setImage)
- override paintComponent method so that:

  - it calls super.paintComponent
  - then executes graphics.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, rootPane) //Well, you may have to fix something about rootPane

Then, in your code:

- jTextPaneStructures must be an instance of your new class (MyTextArea)
- in your listener (you may even want to provide a single method in MyTextArea that performs these three tasks):

  - jTextPaneStructures.setImage(cpImage);
  - jTextPaneStructures.invaliate();
  - jTextPaneStructures.repaint();

Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MyTextArea extends JTextArea implements MouseListener {

   private Image myImage;

   public MyTextArea() {
      addMouseListener(this);
   }

   public void addImage(Image image) {
      this.myImage = image;
      invalidate();
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, this);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
      MyTextArea txt = new MyTextArea();
      f.getContentPane().add(txt);
      f.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Just another component to click on"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("twitter.png"); //place a png image in your working directory for testing
      addImage(img.getImage());

   }

   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

}
```

Comment: Great thanks.I got it.I did not implement MouseListener but went directly to jTextPaneStructuresMouseClicked with jTextPaneStructures.addImage(cpImage); and
jTextPaneStructures.paintComponent(g); in place of jTextPaneStructures.getGraphics().. The greatest problem I had with NetBeans because I had to change the autocode in variable declaration. I finally did it through Notepad and copying the corrected code into a new project file. The code works but I no longer have 'Design' option in NetBeans editor. Do you know if there is any way get 'Design' back with this new file? Great thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you on this. I don't know NetBeans very much. I'm glad you got it, anyway.